# PDF/X: Preflight says Glyphs are missing in embedded font

Tags: pdftex, miktex, acrobat, pdfx

I'm creating a wall calendar using LaTeX. However, in prepress Acrobat 8's preflight says "Glyphs are missing in embedded font" to some glyphs in Roboto Black. It seems only the glyphs `ß`, `5`, `7`, `„`, and `“` are missing.

I tried to create minimal working example, however this works fine!
What could be a reason, the WME works but the real pdf fails?

This is my WME:

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifvtex}
\usepackage[x-3]{pdfx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[light, black, sfdefault]{roboto}

\makeatletter
    \ifcsname UseRawInputEncoding\endcsname \else \let\UseRawInputEncoding\relax \fi
    \begingroup
    \dimen0=0.996264009963\paperwidth\relax
    \edef\pdfx@mwidth{\strip@pt\dimen0}%
    \newdimen\bleed \bleed=3mm
    \advance\dimen0 by -0.996264009963\bleed
    \edef\pdfx@twidth{\strip@pt\dimen0}%
    \dimen0=0.996264009963\paperheight\relax
    \edef\pdfx@mheight{\strip@pt\dimen0}%
    \advance\dimen0 by -0.996264009963\bleed
    \edef\pdfx@theight{\strip@pt\dimen0}%
    \dimen0=0.996264009963\bleed\relax
    \edef\bfcal@bleed{\strip@pt\dimen0}%
    \edef\next{\endgroup\pdfpagesattr{%
        /MediaBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
        /BleedBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
        /CropBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
        /TrimBox[\bfcal@bleed\space \bfcal@bleed\space \pdfx@twidth\space \pdfx@theight]}
    }\next
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \bfseries 
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    
    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
    
    ß ä ö ü 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ? ! ° "` "'
\end{document}
```

*test.xmpdata*

```
\Title{Test}
\Author{}
\Keywords{}
\Publisher{}
\Copyright{}
\setCMYKcolorprofile{PSOcoated_v3.icc}
                    {PSO Coated V3}
                    {PSO Coated V3 (FOGRA51 (ECI))}
                    {http://www.eci.org}
```

*PSOcoated_v3.icc*

For the color profile see: http://www.color.org/registry/PSOcoated_v3.xalter

Comment: You have a working example and a larger one that fails. Now use logic: you only need to find the point where the one turns into the other to know what could be the reason of the failure.

Comment: True, but without *any* idea this might become a "sisyphean work". Therefore I ask for pointers/ideas. ;-)

Comment: It is normally not much work, you only need to move up the \end{document} up and down in the document to exclude large parts. Even in large documents I reduce such problems normally to a manageable size with 10 compilations or so.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since only two digits (`5` and `7`) are reported as missing, you could try constructing a very small example that contains those digits along with a small amount of other typical text.  If the problem really is an "incomplete" font, such a test should result in an error report similar to the one you have already received, and you should also be able to see their absence in the output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As mentioned in my question, a MWE with only the font works fine. So it's not an "incomplete" font. Anyway, a friend was able to "repair" the PDF using professional tools. As soon I have some time, I'll try to dig and find out the real problem. So, thanks anyway! :-)